# Eclipse: WARNING: Unknown device API version

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting the error as in the title of this question. It started when I upgraded my phone from a Samsung S4 to an S7. I've searched StackOverflow (and google) and found no solutions that worked - many responses were 5+ years old.

I've updated everything I could from the SDK Manager. I've rebooted, restarted Eclipse, power cycling phone, reconnecting new USB cable, restarting ADB -- all multiple times. I tried rebuilding/reinstalling some old apps but all give the same error. It seems like the phone is causing the problem (unfortunately my old S4 died so I can't try that).

Other interesting artifacts:

(1) In DDMS the device shows up as "unknown",

(2) Logcat now produces no output.

I've been beating my head on the wall for a week, with no joy. Can anybody offer any suggestions?

Comment: Three things - Assuming you're using Windows, are your Samsung development [USB drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows) up to date? Has Development Mode been enabled on your device? And are you aware that Android development on Eclipse [has been unsupported since mid-2015?](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

Comment: This is likely because Eclipse has been removed from support for a long time now so won't have the latest tools required for newer versions of Android. Give Android Studio a try which is the recommended and supported IDE by Google/Android https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIh_-u8suW2AIV6LDtCh0vvw6pEAAYASAAEgIkY_D_BwE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the old Eclipse base Android development tools has been developed for an now outdated ADB version.

The communication between DDMS and ADB will no longer work as the old DDMS is incompatible with the new ADB API. If you really want to get DDMS work you have to use an old ADB version that matches it.

However the recommended way would be to delete DDMS and the Eclipse based Android development tools and switch to Android Studio.

Comment: Ok, I switched to Android Studio and (after some hair-pulling) logcat seems to work now. I still don't understand why my old, long-used Eclipse-based build no longer worked - the ONLY thing that changed was the phone. But I guess it's water under the bridge now.