# Android virtual device not listed only in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I'm trying to debug my project in eclipse but when i open the android virtual device (avd) window my connected device isn't listed but in the universal adb it is listed and the status is ok.

The device is listed also in android studio.

What can i do to see the device in eclipse??

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: You do realise Android development [has not been supported on Eclipse since 2015](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html), right?

Comment: The question may be slightly different but the answer is the same [Eclipse: WARNING: Unknown device API version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891550/eclipse-warning-unknown-device-api-version)

Comment: yes, i know. so since android development has not been supported on eclipse i can't use a device to debug my project??

Comment: @IgorTurchi Pretty much. ADB tools have had a number of significant changes since work was stopped on the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @MichaelDodd so do you think that i should completely switch to android studio or try to find some strange way to make it work??

Comment: @IgorTurchi Completely switch. There's a wizard that'll [help you import Eclipse projects into Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

Comment: @MichaelDodd thank you very much!!

Comment: @IgorTurchi No worries. I've summarised the above information in an answer so we can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android development support for Eclipse was ended in late 2015 [as per this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).

> To that end and to focus all of our efforts on making Android Studio better and faster, we are ending development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year. This specifically includes the Eclipse ADT plugin and Android Ant build system.

Since that time, there have been [a number of changes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) to the ADB tools & protocol which have not been reflected in the Eclipse plugin due to it being deprecated.

I'd advise continuing your project in Android Studio. There is a wizard that allows you to import Eclipse projects by going to `File > New... > Import Project...` and select the folder for your current Eclipse project. Google have also provided a guide to [migrating from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#migrate-eclipse).